# cakephp setting custom header does not work, htaccess, apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, http-headers, debian

I am experiencing some odd behaviour.

I have debian 7(on the vmware if it matters) with apache 2.2.22. For my cakephp application I want to set custom header, so I put this in app/webroot/.htaccess file (without removing what already exists of course)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
</IfModule>
```

but when I request the page, in firebug net panel it does not show `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header. Headers mod is enabled. `a2enmod headers` outputs `Module headers already enabled`. Apache is restarted (even OS is rebooted). This cakephp application(copied by 100%) I tested on my vps(again debian 7), and it shows that header just fine. So, first it made me believe there is smth wrong with my local debian, but then I tested this. I created single file `index.php` in www/some_test folder and put `echo "ok"`. Also created .htaccess with the same content

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
</IfModule>
```

And the funny part is, I could see in firebug that `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header. So, the bottom line with cakephp application, in the server1 custom headers are fine, in server2 - does not show, for simple index.php 'app' in server2 headers are fine again. Can someone help what the problem can be. I need to set custom headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was the problem, but removing and reinstalling the php solved it

```
apt-get remove php5*
apt-get install php5
```

https://superuser.com/questions/673837/php5-ini-file-is-blank/674408#674408